# Word or phrase for one expecting gratitude and who often boasts about his generosity

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who gives away something expecting a lot of gratitude from the receiver and often brags about his magnanimity?

And what would be the word for such an action?

Comment: preening magnanimity?

Comment: I think the phrase means taking pride in or congratulating oneself on one's generosity, but it doesn't mean that the giver expects gratitude in return from the receiver. Or, does it?

Comment: Counting the cost, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

**[Trumpesque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Trumpesque#English)** (also [Trumpian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Trumpian#English))

Acting in Donald Trump-like manner.

Comment: Before I get voted down for spam, note that I did vote for Trump. But even a #MAGA supporter like me still thinks its a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect fit, but consider:

***Pompous*** -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pompous)

> *adj.* puffed up with vanity
> *adj.* characterized by pomp and ceremony and stately display
>
> A **pompous person** is arrogant or conceited. He'll walk into a party with an inflated ego, ready to tell anyone who will listen that "I'm kind of a big deal."

*pompously* adverb,
*pompousness* noun

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in **pseudo-philanthropist**, along the same lines as 'pseudointellectual':

[**Pseudo-** meaning](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pseudo):

> - not genuine; sham.
> - pretentious or insincere.
> - a pretentious or insincere person.

[**Philanthropist** meaning](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/philanthropist):

> a person who seeks to promote the welfare of others, especially by the generous donation of money to good causes.

Answer (score 0):

**self-congratulatory** (see any dictionary)

Note, however, that expecting some kind of satisfaction from being magnanimous, contributing to charity, or helping others is typical of human nature.

If you look at lists of contributors in the annual reports of charitable organizations, most are named; only a few are anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person would be **self-righteous**:

> **Self-righteous**: Smugly or unduly sure of one's own righteousness ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=self-righteous))

And even more condemnatory term would be **sanctimonious**:

> **Sanctimony:** Righteousness accompanied by an unwarranted attitude of moral or social superiority; smug or hypocritical righteousness ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sanctimony)).

The only downside is that they do not explicitly carry the idea of [munificence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/munificence), though self-righteousness is often associated with providing gifts. Indeed a predominant reference in English and American cultures, would be [Matthew 23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2023&version=NKJV):

> Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! For you pay tithe of mint and anise and cummin, and have neglected the weightier matters of the law: justice and mercy and faith.
>   (...)
>
> Even so you also outwardly appear **righteous** to men, but inside you are full of hypocrisy and lawlessness.

Indeed, it gave the word [pharisaical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pharisaical).